# how to Pass ddl value from html and pass it to if else condtion in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html select tag with several options in it,  I want to make users to select  any one options and depending on the user's selection, pass this in a JS function, and perform varoius actions depending on what is selected by user.
My Problem is that, it does not match user selection with the if else condition, on which my rotate() function will get executed, but it does not work.
here is my code.

```
<table class="table-box">
        <thead>
     <th colsapn="5" style="color:red">
      My Photo Album
        </th>
      </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
        <td id="r1">Roboust</td> 
        <td id="r2">Dynamic</td> 
        <td id="r3">Adhere</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="r4">Popular</td> 
         <td id="r5">Trending</td> 
         <td id="r6">Favourite</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="r7">Famous</td> 
         <td id="r8">Blockbouster</td>
         <td id="r9">Navie</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>Select Box from Below to flip:</p>
        <select id="ddlbox" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Roboust</option>
            <option value="2">Dynamic</option>
            </select>

            <script>
            //var selectDdl = function(ddlbox) {
            var seletion=document.getElementById('ddlbox');
            var selectedText = seletion.options[seletion.selectedIndex].Value;

            if(selectedText == "Roboust")   {
            rotate();
            }
            else {
            alert("Else called");
            }   
            var rotate =function() {
                    document.getElementById('r1').style="transform:rotateX(180deg);transition:0.6s;transform-style:preserve-3d";
</script>
```

Comment: What is the question? You just showed your code and don't say what is wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question..Please update on the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your `GetSelectedTextValue` function which should be something

```
function GetSelectedTextValue (t){
    var selectedText = t.options[t.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    if(selectedText == "Roboust")   {
        rotate();
    }
    else {
        alert("Else called");
    }
}
```

Comment: <select id="ddlbox" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this)">  this is what I used it.

Comment: Yes but there's no such a function in your script tag, so you are invoking a function which does not exist. Alternatively If you just need the selected text of dropdown you can find in my code how to get it